# Concatenate text in PowerShell based on a condition while exporting data to CSV

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-5.0

I have data in AD like below:

```
DisplayName TelephoneNumber
Alex        111-1111
John        222-2222
Peter       333-3333,2051
```

I have a powershell script like below:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=Domain Users,DC=nxcc,DC=local' -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -and (mail -like "*.*") -and (PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -like "*")} -Properties displayname, telephonenumber | select displayname, telephonenumber |  Export-csv -NoTypeInformation -encoding UTF8 -Path "\\myserver\c$\AllUserContactInfo.csv"
```

What I want to do is to add `,0000` at the end of `TelephoneNumber` field if the field does not contain a comma character, while exporting to CSV. So expected output is:

```
DisplayName TelephoneNumber
Alex        111-1111,0000
John        222-2222,0000
Peter       333-3333,2051
```

How can I achieve this? I appreciate any help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
| select displayname, telephonenumber
```

Use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties):

```
| Select-Object DisplayName,
    @{n='TelephoneNumber'; e={($_.TelephoneNumber.Split(',', 2) + '0000')[0,1] -Join ','}}
```

In the expression, the telephone number is split (using the comma as delimiter). This will return only one item in case there is no comma and two items otherwise. Then add `'0000'` to the list (as a second or a third item), than only take the first two items and join them again with a comma.